# Automation server can't create object :unsigned activeX control works on the system where its created but not on any other

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-3.0, activex, cab

I have created an `activeX` control (**not signed**) using `VS 2008` and following [this](http://haseebakhtar.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/creating-an-activex-control-in-net-using-c/) link, and converted it into a `cab` file, which is then placed on the server. When I am accessing the page with the activeX control embedded from the machine in which I created the activeX (which is different from the server), the control is working fine, but if I access the same page on another machine, it shows the infamous error '`Automation server can't create object`'

Everywhere I search for this error, I find that it disappears if I place the site in the '`Trusted`' zone, and customize the security settings for that zone to

```
'Enable' for 'Download unsigned activex controls'
'Disable' for 'Only allow approved domains to use activex without prompt'
'Enable' for 'Initialize and script activex controls not marked as safe for scripting'
'Disable' for 'Allow activex filtering'
```

But, unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. **Something I can't understand is that why does it work on the machine I created the activeX, and not in others even though they have the same IE settings** Has it got anything to do with the control being registered by `Visual Studio` at the time of can creation on the machine in which I created the control?

I don't wish to run any registry-changing commands manually, as this should be done by the cab file itself somehow on client machines

Comment: What's in the windows application and security logs from when you try and create it. Do the machines have different OS or .net Versions etc. Can you create another simple 'hello world' Ax control and see if it has the same characteristics. Can you create an exe that runs the same code- and see if that has issues on the target machine. In other words you need to narrow down the places where it fails and what fails and how it fails to get some clues.

Comment: nothing gets registered in either the security or application logs when this js error comes, and this issue persists even if we make a 'hello world' example, and creating an exe file won't solve solve the issue as the functions are getting triggered on clicking links on an HTML page

Comment: if it happens with another simple example - then it rightly points to environment issue as opposed to control. Next thing would be to isolate the environmental differences, and possible be running procmon etc in the background to see what happens during installation and instantiation.